# Wifi works from one boot drive, but disappeared from the other

Tags: wireless

I have a System 76 Meerkat which I routinely boot from an external SSD, but it also has a bootable, internal SSD. Each of these drives boots to Ubuntu 17.10

While I was using the machine for photo editing today, my cordless USB keyboard stopped working--I changed its batteries without effect, so I plugged in another, wired USB keyboard which worked fine.
After about 30 min. the screen locked up. The only thing working was the mouse pointer's moving about, though it had changed to the letter "X."

I shut the machine down and rebooted (several times, including lengthy waits between tries) but could never reconnect to WiFi.

I then rebooted from the internal drive, and everything worked fine.

When I tried iwconfig after rebooting with the default, external drive, it reported nothing.

Clearly it's not the machine, as it works when booted from one of the drives attached, which leads me to think that some glitch took out the Wifi's settings or a driver stored on the external drive.

Looking at the settings merely tells me there's no WiFi adapter present, and we know there really is one and that it works.

So what's my next step? Help!

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you have 2 OS on separate drives. Check whether either OS have different kernels. Drivers ( modules ) for WiFi may be different between kernels, or have different fixes in them.  Also, worth checking what modules actually do get loaded during boot time. Use `lsmod` for that or `modprobe`

Answer (score 0):

Might be that USB on your system is flaky.

F.ex. the controller not running cleanly. The wiring not being clean any more. One of the connectors having a loose or cold contact.

I had a similar problem with *one* of my USB connectors, i.e. most of the time backups to the external disk would work but sometimes they'd abort because the filesystem would go read-only because of block device access errors.

If you do a `lsusb` then you can see a few things:
* is the wireless interface on the USB bus? Sometimes they are on an internal USB connection. That would point towards the hypothesis above.
* also often you have *multiple* USB buses in one laptop (sometimes USB3 capable buses vs. only USB2 capable ones). Try connecting the drive to the other bus if that helps.

Also, if you had a disk problem due to a flaky USB bus, then there should be traces in your log files, as f.ex. the filesystem of your external drive being forcefully re-checked on boot.

Also, have a look at `/var/log/kern.log*` and at `dmesg`. Can you see the system complaining painfully about any hefty problems?

One other hypothesis could be voltage problems. Your battery being flaky or all the devices drawing too much power. Which would result in *most* devices working correctly but *some* not getting enough voltage.